# Setting xAxis.min breaks area display in two-point highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please have a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gy3bV/1/.

That's a "shortened" version of a bug I am trying to fix in my project.

The fiddle code is as simple as this (mine is more complicated, but the issue is reflected here):

```
$(function () {
    var chartOptions = {
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb'],
            min: 0
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            data: [0, 10],
            name: 'Area'
        }]
    };


    $('#container0').highcharts(chartOptions);
    chartOptions.xAxis.min = 1;
    $('#container1').highcharts(chartOptions);
});
```

So, when `min = 0`, it draws a valid chart with the first point at `x`axis (0 level) and the second one at the level of 10. When `min = 1`, I expect it to just hide the first point and to draw the area as if it goes from hidden `('Jan', 0)` to visible `('Feb', 10)`. However, it just draws a horizontal line at the level of 10.

It behaves as expected with >2 points: http://jsfiddle.net/gy3bV/2/

It does not work when I am passing full coordinates as series (`data: [['Jan', 0], ['Feb', 10]]`): http://jsfiddle.net/gy3bV/3/

I proved that it is not related to first point being 0 - the same results with any other value. It is also not related to using `type: 'area'` - the same behavior with line.

Ideas? What may I be doing wrong? Could that be a highcharts bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your first "working" example has:

```
xAxis: { categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'] }
series: [{ data: [0, 10, 15] }]
```

While the "broken" example has:

```
xAxis: { categories: ['Jan', 'Feb'] }
series: [{ data: [['Jan', 0], ['Feb', 10]] }]
```

The problem arises when you have `min: 1`, and only two values. That means that the graph only shows a single point, which means the x-axis doesn't have any span at all (it shows from 0.999 to 1.001). Because you are so far zoomed in the graph appears to be completely horizontal, as the other points are "lightyears" away on the x-axis, while having rather similar y-values.

In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy3bV/7/) you can see what appears to be a rather strange animation of the process. However, if we go slowly, it becomes more clear that the other points are infact there, just far far away. Take note of how the y-axis never changes, so the points have to be moved so far out that the y-axis difference can't be spotted:

- [JSFiddle zoom in](http://jsfiddle.net/gy3bV/8/)
- [JSFiddle zoom out](http://jsfiddle.net/gy3bV/9/)

You will have to make sure that your x-axis spans more than a single value, for example with `min: 1, max: 2` or adding more points. If you want to be true to the values being dates you should consider changing to `type: 'datetime'`.

Comment: I have example 0 (my initial code) at the very top of the question - it is exactly the same as example 1 (the one you reference as the first "working" example), but has 2 points, so I think I compare correctly.

Comment: As for "the x-axis doesn't have any span at all" - it has some free space at the left, added by default and filled with chart. Why does this space fill when we have three points (or max = 2), but does not fill in my case? What's the principal difference?

Comment: Ah, yes. I see. Then of course your comparison is correct. The problem is still that the x-axis only shows a single point (from 1 to 1). It must display a range in order for the graph to be slanted. The difference is that with no span it's really just a one-dimensional graph, with that dimension being Y in your case.

Comment: If you check the `xAxis` of the chart the actual values are from `min: 0.999` to `max: 1.001`, which is enough to give it width, and also show the "end" of your series, but not enough span to show the graph slanting on the left side.

Comment: but with 3 points, or with max, it is not extrapolating or something, but draws an exact segment from hidden (Jan, 0) to visible (Feb, 10). It means it builds the hidden point in that case. Why not in two-point case then?

Comment: Yes, it's quite interesting that the outside points don't seem to be drawn when x-axis has equal min and max. Adding more points doesn't "solve" it though ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/gy3bV/6/)). You still need to have a x-axis with min and max not being the same. I'm guessing the answer is somewhere in the source code on this one.

Comment: I updated my answer with two animations that helped myself in understanding just how "close up" I was viewing that single point. Perhaps you'll find them useful as well. In any case, a really interesting question.